# PTIJ: Can Mr. Potato Head be Mekayem וְאָכַלְתָּ֣ פְרִֽי־בִטְנְךָ֗ through eating Kugel?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Are the Tochachas in [Devarim 28:53](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.28.53?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) cursing Mr. Potato Head that he will eat Kugel, potatoes in Cholent, Latkes, Knishes, and many other Jewish potatular (yes, a made-up word) cuisines?

Since when is eating delicious food **considered the punishment**?

By the way, what does Mr. Potato Head eat during Pesach, if potatoes are off-limits?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: . בטנך in your tin and not someone else’s tin.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "tin" @Dr.Shmuel?

Comment: @Moish I.e. kugel may only be served in a tin pan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely not!

The verse says **פרי** בטנך - the **fruit** of your stomach. Potatoes are vegetables.

Comment: Surely you make a בורא פרי האדמה on them.

Comment: @DonielF *bedi'eved*, as you know. But, the question is not about brachot. And, seriously, considering that Mr. Potato Head is raw, he would say *shehakol* if he ate himself, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

No, one may only fulfill this by eating Cholent (which contains meat and potatoes), as it continues: "בְּשַׂר בָּנֶיךָ וּבְנֹתֶיךָ".

Comment: Surely the "meat" of Mr. Potato's offspring is also potato?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Potatoes [grow from their eyes](https://simple.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuber) and not from the bellies, so Mr. Potato Head has the next verse in the Tochachas, [Devarim 28:54](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.28.54?lang=bi&aliyot=0):

> הָאִישׁ֙ הָרַ֣ךְ בְּךָ֔ וְהֶעָנֹ֖ג מְאֹ֑ד תֵּרַ֨ע עֵינ֤וֹ בְאָחִיו֙ וּבְאֵ֣שֶׁת חֵיק֔וֹ וּבְיֶ֥תֶר בָּנָ֖יו אֲשֶׁ֥ר יוֹתִֽיר׃
>
> He who is most tender and fastidious among you shall be evil with his eye to his brother and the wife of his bosom and the children he has spared.